# Missing elected year on moderators' users page in meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, users

On the main site's [/users?tab=moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) it shows the year that the user was elected as a moderator under their reputation.

[image]

However, on meta's [/users?tab=moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) the year of election is missing.

[image]

Comment: They were not elected on Meta ;)

Comment: @Oded Fair enough :)